# Googlebot keeps indexing old pages

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap

Recently, I moved all pages from `subdomain.domain.com/<lang>/` to `<lang>.subdomain.domain.com` and submitted new sitemap.xml in Google Search console inteface.

From the server logs, I see that GoogleBot keeps trying to index old pages located at `subdomain.domain.com/<lang>/` and throws errors in Coverage report. How can I stop Google to index those pages?

Will adding

```
Disallow: /en/
Disallow: /it/
Disallow: /fr/
etc...
```

into robots.txt help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am amazed I didn't think about 301 redirects. If I configured it back in April, my site's crawl speed would be so much faster since search engines would not have to deal with all those 404 responses.